# Can I avoid using structural typing in this scenario?

Tags: scala

I have some code that uses both a third-party library and my own library. In my own library, I don't want to have a dependency on the third-party one so I want one of my methods to accept a more generic type as a parameter. Unfortunately, I cannot extend or mixin a trait to the 3rd party classes since they are generated using factory methods & the classes are `final`.

I can get around this issue by using structural typing but I was wondering if there is an alternative? I don't want to have to iterate through each record returned by the factory method and "new up" instances of a separate type if possible.

I've boiled it down to a scenario like the following:

#### Third-party library code that cannot be changed

```scala
// Class inside library cannot be extended due to it being 'final'
final class SpecificRecord(val values: IndexedSeq[String]) {
  def get(i: Int): String = {
    values(i)
  }

}

// A companion object simply to create some sample data in an iterator
object SpecificRecord{
  def generateSpecificRecords(): Iterator[SpecificRecord] = new Iterator[SpecificRecord] {
    var pointerLocation: Int = 0

    private val state = IndexedSeq(
      IndexedSeq("Row1 Col1", "Row1 Col2", "Row 1 Col3"),
      IndexedSeq("Row2 Col1", "Row2 Col2", "Row 2 Col3")
    )

    override def hasNext: Boolean = {
      if (pointerLocation < state.length) true else false
    }

    override def next(): SpecificRecord = {
      val record = new SpecificRecord(state(pointerLocation))
      pointerLocation += 1
      record
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see above, the `SpecificRecord` class is final and the `specificRecords` val is an Iterator with a bunch of `SpecificRecord` in it. I don't want to have to iterate through each `specificRecord` and create a new, more generic, object if possible.

#### My code that can be changed

```scala
val specificRecords: Iterator[SpecificRecord] = SpecificRecord.generateSpecificRecords()

type gettable = {
  def get(i: Int): String
}

def printRecord(records: Iterator[gettable]): Unit = {
  for (record <- records) {
    println(record.get(0), record.get(1), record.get(2))
  }
}

printRecord(specificRecords)
```

This correctly prints:

```
(Row1 Col1,Row1 Col2,Row 1 Col3)
(Row2 Col1,Row2 Col2,Row 2 Col3)
```

I have a `printRecord` method that doesn't really care what type is passed in, as long as it has a method like `get(Int): String`. This a pretty decent solution but I was wondering if it would be possible to do this without structural typing?

Comment: You can define a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) if you find that better or worse is up to you, check [this](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4) for a comparison of both techniques _(and more)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical use case for type classes.

```
trait Gettable[T] { 
   def get(t: T, i: Int): String
}

object Gettable {
    implicit object SpecificRecordGettable extends Gettable[SpecificRecord] {
        def get(sr: SpecificRecord, i: Int) = sr.get(i)
    }
}

def printRecord[T : Gettable](records: Iterator[T]) = {
  val getter = implicitly[Gettable[T]]
  records.foreach { record => 
    println(getter.get(record, 0), getter.get(record, 1), getter.get(record, 2))
  }
}
```

This is a bit more verbose than your approach with structured types: for each type you want to be `gettable`, you have to add an implicit object implementing the `get`, but it works without reflection, which is a good thing.

Another advantage of this approach is its flexibility: the underlying type does not have to have `get` specifically, you can implement anything with the implicit. E.g.:

```
   implicit object ArrayGettable extends Gettable[Array[String]] {
      def get(a: Array[String], i: Int) = a(i)
   }

   implicit object ProductGettable extends Gettable[Product] {
      def get(p: Product, i: Int) = p.productIterator.drop(i).next.toString
   }
```

Now, your `printRecord` works with string arrays too (as long as they have at least three elements), and even tuples and case classes.
Try this:

```
printRecord[Product](Iterator((1,2, "three"), ("foo", "bar", 5)))
```

Or this:

```
case class Foo(x: String, y: Int, z: Seq[Int])
printRecord[Product](Iterator(Foo("bar", 1, 1::2::Nil), ("foo", "bar", "baz")))
```

A similar but a little bit less verbose approach is to just define an implicit 'getter' without bothering with type classes:

```
def printRecord[T](records: Iterator[T])(implicit getter: (T,Int) => String) = 
  records.foreach { record => 
    println(getter(record, 0), getter(record, 1), getter(record, 2))
  }

object Getters {
   implicit def getter(sr: SpecificRecord, i: Int) = sr.get(i)
   implicit def getter(a: Array[String], i: Int) = a(i)
   implicit def getter(p: Product, i: Int) = p.productIterator.drop(i).next.toString
}
```

This is fairly equivalent in usage, the difference being that type class lets you potentially define more than one method, but if you only ever need `get`, then this would save you a few keystrokes.

Comment: Great answer Dima thanks! I was struggling to understand type classes so this helped a lot.